# Is WSO2's DSS (Data Services Server) outdated and replaced?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Trying to follow along with wso2's [how-to-write-a-web-application-backed-by-wso2-middleware-part-1](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/02/how-to-write-a-web-application-backed-by-wso2-middleware-part-1/) which is their up-to-date introduction for it, but it is 4 years old. One of the steps is downloading and [installing the DSS](https://wso2.com/library/webinars/2014/05/data-management-at-your-fingertips-with-wso2-data-services-server/), but the documentation states that this is 
[image: Archived content]. 
But I cannot find any tool by which this has been replaced. Not in AM nore EI.

Also all DSS-related questions here are more then 3-years old.

What is the new DSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data services server (DSS) is now a part of WSO2 EI. You can find the documentation here.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Data+Services

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed where it got transported to.